# How to name a Java variable "public"

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm deserializing an object that has a variable with the name of public that is a primitive boolean. intelliJ keeps thinking public is the modifier. How do I disable Java from thinking it's a modifier?

Comment: *"How do I disable Java from thinking it's a modifier?"* You can't, use a different name.

Comment: You can't name a variable `public`. Just like you can't name a variable `class` or `true`. http://www.jwrider.com/riderist/java/javaidrs.htm

Comment: you dont! It is a keyword you are not allowed to use a variable name. Instead you have to create a variable and annotate it in some way for gson to map the json-field "public" to it. http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/

Comment: Can you post the code? I have a feeling you're looking for the @SerializedName annotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The best you can do is muck with the serialization process itself and change the variable name (e.g, with [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)). If you can't do that, you're kind of stuck.

Note that this is true only of Java source code. Compiled .class files can have variables, class names, etc., that are the same as Java key words. Some code obfuscators take advantage of this to make it very difficult to decompile into legal Java.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@SerializedName("public")` annotation for such variable.